# .props setting OutDir

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, vsprops

Trying to setup two parallel environments, with a separate .sln's, but the same vcxproj's, since I'm working with 100+ projects.  I want different OutDir and IntermediateDir's, so I put this in the variant props file for each configuration:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <OutDir Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">$(Configuration)5\</OutDir>
  <IntDir Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">$(Configuration)5\</IntDir>
  <OutDir Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">$(Configuration)5\</OutDir>
  <IntDir Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">$(Configuration)5\</IntDir>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Same without the 5's in the other .props.  Seems to work ok for building, but for starting apps, it tries to find things in SolutionDir/Release5/foo.exe instead of foodir/Release/foo.exe.  I assume this is because of the relative path being parsed incorrectly.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out that `<OutputFile>` also needed to be tweaked.  I just made it defined in terms of $(OutDir) and it resolved the problem